# How do I write the policy statement of an encrypted SQS for S3 events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-sqs, amazon-kms

I have an SQS queue which **used** to have the following policy doc. for receiving S3 events from a bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "example-ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<>:cypher-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:cypher-secondarybucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I have enabled Server-side encryption(SSE) for the queue. And, I have followed [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html) for writing the policy statement for encryption. The policy statement now, looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "example-ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<>:cypher-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:cypher-secondarybucket"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<>:cypher-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:cypher-secondarybucket"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:<>:cypher-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:cypher-secondarybucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But now, the queue is not getting any messages from the bucket on file additions. **Is there something wrong which I did with the permissions?**

Comment: In trying to reproduce your scenario, I was *unable* to add an Event Notification to an encrypted SQS queue. It returned an Internal Error message. However, I suspect that the policies you copied from the [SQS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html) should go on the IAM User that is sending the message, rather than on the SQS queue itself.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah. A silly mistake on my part. Didn't notice that SSE-enabled queues are not supported for S3 events.  Self-answered it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have missed the following announcement from the [same article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html).  A very silly mistake on my part.  Will need to wait for sending S3 events to encrypted SQS.

> The following features of AWS services aren't currently compatible
>   with encrypted queues:
>
> Amazon CloudWatch Events
>
> Amazon S3 Event Notifications
>
> Amazon SNS Topic Subscriptions
>
> Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks
>
> AWS IoT Rule Actions
>
> AWS Lambda Dead-Letter Queues

Comment: Ah! Well, that explains the error I encountered too!

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible. From the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3 under the section **AWS KMS Key Policy**

> If the SQS queue is SSE enabled, you can attach the following key
>   policy to the associated AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) customer
>   managed customer master key (CMK). The policy grants the Amazon S3
>   service principal permission for specific AWS KMS actions that are
>   necessary for to encrypt messages added to the queue.
>
> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Id": "example-ID",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": {
>                 "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
>             },
>             "Action": [
>                 "kms:GenerateDataKey",
>                 "kms:Decrypt"
>             ],
>             "Resource": "*"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Comment: What about the default KMS (alias/aws/sqs) ?

Comment: According to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947804/sqs-encryption-using-cmk, it’s not possible

Comment: Why is `kms:Decrypt` needed?

Comment: @jellycsc guessing here but I think it's because it's receiving the S3 event encrypted by a KMS key associated with S3 and then decrypting it and re-encrypting with a KMS key associated with SQS (hence the GenerateDataKey).

Comment: @dustin.schultz Decrypting encrypted s3 event doesn't require `kms:Decrypt` action on the KMS key resource associated with SQS.

Comment: @jellycsc kms:decrypt is needed. The answer comes directly from the AWS documentation. My previous comment ... being a guess ... was incorrect. However, if you spend a little bit of time reading, you’ll see the answer is in the documentation: “When the data key reuse period expires ... the next call triggers a call to to kms:GenerateDataKey and kms:decrypt to verify the integrity of the new data key before using it”. So it may work without it at first but it will fail when the data key reuse period expires.

Comment: @dustin.schultz By "verifying the integrity of the new data key", do you mean decrypting the encrypted copy of the data key (`CiphertextBlob`), and see if the result matches the plaintext data key?