# SQS Encryption using CMK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to read message from an encrypted SQS. Objects are landed on an S3 Bucket -> Trigger S3 Event -> Message sent to SQS -> SQS triggers Lambda to Process.

I have got this working using an AWS managed CMK. However, I can't get this working using AWS owned CMK e.g. `alias/aws/sqs`.

The message just goes into `messages in flight` and does not invoke the Lambda functions.

As per the the AWS documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-server-side-encryption.html#sqs-encryption-what-does-sse-encrypt `If you don't specify a custom CMK, Amazon SQS uses the AWS managed CMK for Amazon SQS`. But we can't attach any policies against AWS owned CMK e.g.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [{
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "Service": "<<service>>.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": [
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:Decrypt"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
       }]
}
```

My question is: is it possible to use the AWS owned CMK on an SQS and have Lambda functions be able to read from that queue?

There is a section in the above URL called `Enable Compatibility between AWS Services Such as Amazon CloudWatch Events, Amazon S3, and Amazon SNS and Encrypted Queues`.

It mentions attaching a policy to the CMK. However, there is an option to use the `alias/aws/sqs`. I was wondering if I was missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spoke with AWS and KMS AWS Managed Key would not work in this scenario. We can't change the key policy for KMS AWS Managed Keys, so wouldn't be possible for scenario: S3 Bucket -> Trigger S3 Event -> Message sent to SQS -> SQS triggers Lambda to Process

I used KMS AWS Customer Managed Key and it worked fine.